# Declaring a JS library for use with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-address, definitelytyped

There are many threads for similar issues, but as far as I can tell this one is unique.

I'm using [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) plugin in my app and would like to use it in a TypeScript file. Unfortunately there is no [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) script available for the library. When I try to use jQuery.address, I get:

```
The property 'address' does not exist on value of type 'jQueryStatic'
```

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082266/how-can-i-create-a-template-for-a-typescript-file), I've tried to define `address` inside of `jquery.d.ts`:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    address(options): any;
    ...
}
```

And I think this seems to work for $.address(); but not for any of address' methods. I've also tried to create my own .d.ts file per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12703866/1308734), but still no luck. And I tried using `declare` in a .d.ts file. No luck.

The only method that I need to use is the `parameter` method...

```
$.address.parameter('param', 1);
```

In which case I get:

```
The property 'parameter' does not exist on value of type 'address'
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

edit: I'm working in a Visual Studio C# .net environment, if that helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not need to edit `jquery.d.ts` itself; put these definitions in their own file so they can be maintained properly. Something minimal would be like this:

```
// For methods on e.g. $('a')
interface JQuery {
    address(callback?: () => void): JQuery;
}

// For methods on $
interface JQueryStatic {
    address: JQueryAddressStatic;
}

interface JQueryAddressStatic {
    (): JQuery;
    parameter(name: string): string;
    parameter(name: string, value: string, append?: boolean): JQuery;
}
```

Comment: YES! That did it. And much better creating a new file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The following goes inside `jquery.d.ts`:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    address(options): JQueryAddress;
}

interface JQueryAddress {
    parameter(name, value): any;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. That solved the 'address' issue but I still get "The property 'parameter' does not exist on value of type 'address'". So $.address() works, but $.address.parameter() doesn't.

Comment: Don't edit existing .d.ts file to add interface members -- interfaces are open and can be extended by simply declaring another interface block of the same name.