# Working with KendoUI, TypeScript and DefinitelyTyped

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, kendo-ui, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm working with an old version of KendoUI (v2013.2.716) and TypeScript (v 0.9.5). I would update, but everything breaks and I'm on a tight deadline. Will do that later.

Anyway, I'm using the DefinitelyTyped `kendo.d.ts` and everything was fine until I tried this:

```
var grid = $('.k-grid').data('kendoGrid');
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = newDataSource;
grid.dataSource.read();
```

This works fine, but Visual Studio doesn't like it. I get:

```
The property 'transport' does not exist on value of type 'kendo.data.DataSource'
```

I've [had issues like this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113589/declaring-a-js-library-for-use-with-typescript) and pretty sure I can make a `custom.d.ts` file to work around this error, but not sure how. Does anyone know how I can create a workaround?

Comment: "I would update, but everything breaks" haha yeah, that is the story of TypeScript. I was on a project using TS for 8 months, and every single update was a nightmare. At some point I just started casting everything to `<any>` and forgot about strong types.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'extend' existing type interfaces by simply declaring them twice, they will be merged.

So, this:

```
interface A {
    propB: string;
}
interface A {
    propC: number;
}
```

Will be treated by the compiler as:

```
interface A {
    propB: string;
    propC: number;
}
```

In your case you can add a custom declaration file, and add the following:

```
module kendo {
    interface data {
        interface DataSource {
            transport: any;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can add typings for transport as well.

Comment: Thanks. With `interface kendo.data.DataSource {...}` I get errors on the first `.` ... "could not find symbol 'data'.

Comment: Ah my bad, you'll need to specify it in the structure as they have in the definition file. I've updated what I guess should be the structure, but you'll need to confirm

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying but still no luck :( I created a Gist to explain what I've tried. https://gist.github.com/dmathisen/10481517

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues.
Most of the times, I fixed it by **casting it to any**.

Try this -

```
 (<any>grid.dataSource.transport).options.read.url = newDataSource;
```

Or, you can try this too -

```
(<kendo.data.DataSource>.grid.dataSource).transport.options.read.url = newDataSource;
```

But, fist option should work for sure!

Hope, this helps

Comment: Thanks. The first doesn't work. The only thing that sort of worked was `(<kendo.data.DataSource>grid.dataSource.transport).options.read.url = newDataSource;`. But then I get `The property 'read' does not exist on value of type 'kendo.data.DataSourceOptions'` :( Tried a combination of different things too.

Comment: try this -->  (<any>grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url) = newDataSource;

Comment: try this -->  (<any>grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url) = newDataSource; OR this ->  (<any>(<any>grid.dataSource.transport).options.read).url = newDataSource;

Comment: Eh. I appreciate the help, but I've tried your suggestions and a ton of related formats, but still no luck :( I'm losing hope.

Comment: It is `transport` this isn't set up in the definition file, so you can't include that in the parenthesis. The correct format would be `(<any>grid.dataSource).transport.options.read.url` or even less strong typing by casting `grid` directly to an `any` : `(<any>grid).dataSource.transport.options.read.url`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly elegant answer, but here's what I do on a tight deadline:

`grid.dataSource['transport'].options.read.url = newDataSource;`

To me this is generally not advised as the whole reason you're using typescript is to maintain type safety, however in the case of 3rd party libraries I do make exceptions here and there by casting to any or using indexer syntax as above.